# nsis - how to set "Next" button as default button

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

I have two custom pages.

In the first custom page, the default button (triggered on `<Enter>`) is the `Next` button.

In the second custom page, I set the default button to a different button:

```
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${DM_SETDEFID} 1221 0
```

But when I click `Back` going back to the first custom page, the default button there is no longer `Next` (i.e. `<Enter>` no longer triggers `Next`).

How do I set the default button in the first custom page back to `Next` button?

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
GetDlgItem $1 "$HWNDPARENT" 1
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${DM_SETDEFID} $1 0
```

**EDIT:**

Code and file structure is actually complicated, but I'll try to simplfiy:

**Dialog1.nsh**

```
Function fnc_Dialog1_Create
    ; create dialog controls here
    Call SetupDialog1
FunctionEnd

Function SetupDialog1
    ; create event handlers here
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

**Dialog2.nsh**

```
Function fnc_Dialog2_Create
    ; create dialog controls here
    ${NSD_CreateButton} 217.87u 126.15u 78.33u 14.15u "$(TRANSLATED_DLG_BUTTON_TESTCONNECTION)"
    Call SetupDialog2
FunctionEnd

Function SetupDialog2
    ; create event handlers here
    ; set Default Button (prevent "Install" on <Enter> by setting default button to a different button
    SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${DM_SETDEFID} 1221 0
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question? You need to post more example code because I cannot reproduce this...

Comment: Next button IS default by default - can you post more code?

Comment: @Slappy yes `Next` button is the default button in Dialog1. When I reach Dialog2, I set the default button to a different button in that dialog (to prevent triggering `Install` upon `<Enter>` since Dialog2 is the last dialog) using `DM_SETDEFID`. However when I go back to Dialog1, it seems `Next` is no longer the default button, because pressing `<Enter>` no longer advances the screen to Dialog2

Comment: @Anders Sorry I deleted the first one because I think this question is more understandable.

Comment: @Obay Without the ${NSD_*} line that creates the control with id 1221 I cannot help, please post code that actually reproduces the issue...

Comment: @Anders I added the actual `${NSD_CreateButton}`. It's `1221` because I read somewhere that controls in custom pages are numbered sequentially starting from `1200`.

Comment: @Obay Should you not be using 1201 then?

Comment: @Anders nope because it's the 22nd control to be created. Anyway, that is not my issue. My issue is that once I set the default button to that button, the default button for the other screens become disabled.

Comment: @Obay I have already told you that I cannot reproduce the problem. Why is it so hard for you to post code that reproduces the problem? Here is my code http://pastebin.com/rjfQwiK5 (If you want me to help you then you need to post a full example that reproduces the problem and the NSIS version you are using)